# "@Parameter = null" in Where clause SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, null, where-clause

I have a record in tbl that is queried using the below query.

```
    SELECT *
    FROM tbl
    WHERE Column1 = 'A'
    AND Column2 = 'B'
    AND Column3 IS NULL
```

I have an SP where I have input parameters that I need to query records using those parameters and one example is below which I would like to return the record above but also return data if say @Parameter3 = 'C'.  What is the proper syntax?  Does "AND (Column3 = @PARMETER3 or @PARMETER3 is null) return multiple records?  I would only like the single record above.  Thanks.

```
DECLARE @PARAMETER1 VARCHAR (150),
        @PARAMETER2 VARCHAR (150),
        @PARAMETER3 VARCHAR (150)

SELECT  @PARAMETER1 = 'A',
        @PARAMETER2 = 'B',
        @PARAMETER3 = NULL

SELECT *
    FROM tbl
    WHERE Column1 = @PARAMETER1
    AND Column2 = @PARAMETER2
    AND Column3 = @PARMETER3
```

Comment: `AND Column3 = ISNULL(@PARMETER3, Column3)`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
    FROM tbl
    WHERE Column1 = @PARAMETER1
    AND Column2 = @PARAMETER2
    AND ISNULL(Column3, '') = ISNULL(@PARMETER3, '') --PARAMETER3?
```

Should work if `''` is not normally a valid value for `Column3`.

Answer (score 0):

if you have and index in Column3 and you use:

```
AND ISNULL(Column3, '') = ISNULL(@PARMETER3, '')
```

It will be inefficient. You should use:

```
AND Column3 = ISNULL(@PARMETER3, Column3)
```

Answer (score 0):

using red query:

```
  DECLARE @PARAMETER1 VARCHAR (150),
  @PARAMETER2 VARCHAR (150),
  @PARAMETER3 VARCHAR (150)
  SELECT  @PARAMETER1 = 'A',
  @PARAMETER2 = 'B',
  @PARAMETER3 = 'IS NULL'
  declare @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
  set @sql ='SELECT *    FROM tbl    WHERE Column1 = ' + @PARAMETER1+   
 'AND  Column2 = ' +  @PARAMETER2+    'AND Column3 ' +    @PARAMETER3 
  execute (@sql) -- to select query
```